# Boo Interpreter Speed - Web application

Tags: asp.net, boo

I tried looking for a similar question, but couldn't find one.

I have a ASPNET1.1 web application that is business-oriented. And there are many rules which are hardcoded in the application.

I want to start using Boo as an scripting language which developers can use to write some logic there (not final users).

Whenever a change in the BL is done, I would just update the "script file", deploy to server and that's it. No need for compilation. This is important.

So I have two questions:

1. It seems only CS-Script and Boo support NET1.1 and I don't like CSScript because it requires an exe or a compiled dll for each script. Is Boo the right choice? I wanted to use JINT (NET2.0+) or LUA (couldn't find a way to import to C#).
2. How fast is to execute Boo? I don't want to compile it (I know this is fast since it will be a static language). I want to only use the Boo interpreter Eval function.

By the way, the business logic I want to execute is simple. It should only be something like:

```
function(a, b)
{
return a["Type"] == b["Type"];
}
```

where a and b are simply Hashtables or DataRow. So I actually don't really need the System imports and all that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm discarding Boo because even though I wanted to only use the Eval method, Boo automatically compiles the expression and loads that Assembly generated into the AppDomain.

Since I'm running in ASPNET1.1 and a big web application (thousands of users) that will not be efficient nor fast.

Even if I create an internal AppDomain and run the script in there so the memory is restored.

If I run in the same AppDomain, the memory would be eaten and eaten because those new assemblies will be loaded and never unloaded.

So I guess from Ricardo's response on some forums, that was never the intention of Boo language being designed as CLR language, but it beats the whole "scripting" halo put around Boo.

**This is a big boo for Boo :(**

I just tested LuaInterface 1.3.0 (the last one that supports NET1.1) and it has footprint zero. No assemblies are created and is just plain better in general (more javascript-like, no footprint, etc).

I just hope 1.3.0 version will be stable enough. There is no way I can upgrade my app to NET2.0 in the near future.

IMPORTANT UPDATE:
LuaInterface and luanet had a lot of memory leaks!!!! Instead I linked directly to the lua52.dll by using DllImport and using as a basis the following file:  https://simpleot.googlecode.com/svn-history/r32/SimpleOT/trunk/SimpleOT/Scripting/Lua.cs

I used lua52 because it had support for VC++2003.